How to Improve Extraction of English Questions from Scanned UPSC PDFs with OCR?
I'm working on a project to extract English questions from scanned UPSC exam papers (prelims and mains). These papers include both English and Hindi text. Additionally, the text quality in the PDFs can be poor, leading to extraction challenges.
Here's what i have tried so far:
I used Tesseract OCR to extract text from the scanned PDFs. While it works to some extent, the extracted text contains a lot of noise, especially from Hindi parts and poor-quality scans.
#For this i am using last year (2023) General Studies Paper 1
url = 'https://upsc.gov.in/sites/default/files/QP-CSM-23-GENERAL-STUDIES-PAPER-I-180923.pdf'
response = response.get(url)
pdf_bytes = BytesIO(response.content)

def extract_text_from_scanned_pdf(pdf_bytes):
    doc = fitz.open(stream=pdf_bytes, filetype="pdf")
    extracted_text = ""

    # Iterate through each page
    #Not taking first page since it just have set of instructions
    for page_num in range(1,len(doc)):
        page = doc[page_num]  

        # Convert page to image (using PyMuPDF)
        pix = page.get_pixmap(matrix=fitz.Matrix(2, 2))  
        img = Image.frombytes("RGB", [pix.width, pix.height], pix.samples)
        img_cv2 = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_cv2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        _, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.fromarray(thresh), lang='eng', config='--psm 11')

        
        extracted_text += text + "\n" 

    # Close the PDF document
    doc.close()

    return extracted_text

Is there any better way to extract and clean from such noisy scanned PDFs?
Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
